# How to change the Button text using JS?

Tags: wordpress

I have this button in my WordPress site that says ENROLL THIS COURSE. I want it to show ADD TO CARD. Can anyone provide me with custom JavaScript. Can anyone help me please?

ENROLL THIS COURSE